# Rollup like iife output with babel

Tags: babeljs, rollup

Is it possible to compile ES6 modules to IIFE similar to how the `iife` output option of Rollup works?

I found a plugin `babel-plugin-transform-modules-iife`, which was inspired by the `iife` option of rollup. But the plugin just wraps the module source in an IIFE, and expects the imported module to be already loaded, whereas Rollup  merges the imported module source to the bundle output.